# Error with cv2.minAreaRect , gives me Error related to convex hull function which i haven't used

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

In the code below I have tried to find out if an object is green in colour and draw a contour around it. With that information I would also like to find the corners of the shape and crop it, but I get an error related to the ConvexHull function which I have not used in the code. I have used python 3 and Opencv 3.2.0

The code that I have written gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/SelfDrivingCar/code/picamsense2.py", line 29, in <module>
    points = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
error: /home/pi/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp:136: error: (-215) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function convexHull
```

Here is my code

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np 
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(5)
camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/piImage/image.jpg')
camera.stop_preview()
img = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Desktop/piImage/image.jpg', 1)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([46, 100, 100])
upper = np.array([86, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange (hsv, lower, upper)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (7,5),0 )
erosion =cv2.erode(blur, (5,5), iterations = 3)
contour =np.array( cv2.findContours(erosion, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1])
cv2.drawContours(img, contour, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
for cnt in contour:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.04*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
    if len (approx)== 3:
        print "triangle"
    elif len (approx) == 4 :
        print "quadrilateral"
    elif len(approx) > 4:
        print "circle"        
points = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
points = cv2.boxPoints(points)
points = np.int0(points)
for p in points :
    pt = (p[0],p[1])
    print pt
print points
cv2.imshow('eroded', blur)
cv2.imshow('original', img)
while (1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if(k == 27):
     break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have been trying to look for a fix for quiet some time now

Any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

-Sam

Comment: "rotatedRect" uses the _rotating caliper_ algorithm, whichbis probably implemented along with convex hull code. Be sure that: 1) you're not passing an empty vector to rotatedRect, and that your vector is either int (CV_32S) or float (CV_32F). Also you should not pass an array of array of points (contours), but an array of points (like cnt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are making is that you are passing an array of contours to a function that expects a contour.

Here is a piece of code as illustration. It computes the bounding boxes of all the separate contours in the contour array and stores them in a list.

```
rectangles = []
for cont in contour:
    rectangles.append(cv2.minAreaRect(cont))
```

Comment: Thanks guys helped me a lot

Comment: Cool, but then you need to mark your question as answered by selecting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Posting here in case anybody else got this error with a seemingly valid input:

In my case the problem was caused by passing a sliced numpy array to the `cv2.minAreaRect` function (with `vertex.shape = (4, 3)` )

```
# This won't work and will raise the following error:
# error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp:137: error: (-215) total >= 0 && (depth == 5 || depth == 4) in function convexHull

cv2.minAreaRect(vertices[:, :2])
```

I had to pass a copy of the array to make it work:

```
# This works fine!
cv2.minAreaRect(vertices[:, :2].copy())
```

This is a strange issue and I'm unsure why the second one works.

Answer (score 2):

I received a similar issue to @Maghoumi

```
a = np.array([[176,52],[174,132],[94,92]])
print(a==from_cnt, a.shape==from_cnt.shape)
_, _, angleA = cv2.minAreaRect(a)
_, _, angle0 = cv2.minAreaRect(from_cnt)
```

Yields the following print statements

```
[[ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]] True
```

This indicates that `from_cnt` is exactly the same as `a`. Yet no error occurs for `angleA`, while `angle0` receives the same error as the author.

In this case, using `from_cnt.copy()` did not help.

What appears to be the difference is

```
print(a.dtype, from_cnt.dtype)
```

```
int64 uint8
```

Changing `from_cnt`'s `dtype` to `np.int64` with `from_cnt.astype(np.int64)` worked.